# Tangent spaces of SO(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

My major is mechanical engineering. Recently, I'm reading a paper about tangent spaces of rotation group SO(3). The following is a part of it.

[image: Definition for tangent spaces of rotation manifold SO(3)]

The notations used in the figure are: $\mathbf I $ is the 3$\times$3 identity matrix, $\mathbf R=exp(\widetilde{\psi}) $ is an arbitrary rotation tensor on SO(3), and $\widetilde{\psi}$ and $\widetilde{\theta}$ represent the associated skew-symmetric tensors for vectors $\psi$ and $\theta$, respectively.

According to this paper, there are two definitions for tangent spaces of SO(3), given by Makinen and Simo et al. respectively.

Here are my questions:

1) Which definition is more precise and why?

2) Is an element $\widetilde{\theta}_{R}$ of any tangent space $T_{R}SO(3)$ a skew-symmetric tensor, as Makinen stated?

Thank you very much!

References:

*Mäkinen, Jari*, [**Rotation manifold $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and its tangential vectors**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00466-008-0293-z), Comput. Mech. 42, No. 6, 907-919 (2008). [ZBL1163.74472](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1163.74472).

*Simo, J.C.; Vu-Quoc, L.*, [**On the dynamics in space of rods undergoing large motions - A geometrically exact approach**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(88)90073-4), Comput. Methods Appl. Mech. Eng. 66, No.2, 125-161 (1988). [ZBL0618.73100](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0618.73100).

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Lie}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}$This is a mathematical answer, and may require post-processing (e.g., translation back into engineering language) to be useful to you as an engineer.

In general, if $G$ is a Lie group (such as the rotation group $SO(n)$) and $\Lie{g} = T_{e}G$ is its Lie algebra (such as $\Lie{so}(n)$, the space of skew-symmetric $n \times n$ real matrices), the tangent bundle is trivial via
$$
G \times \Lie{g} \simeq TG,\quad
(g, v) \mapsto (L_{g})_{*}(v).
$$

If $G \subset \Reals^{n^{2}}$ is a matrix group, then $\Lie{g}$ may be identified with a vector subspace of $\Reals^{n^{2}}$, and the bundle isomorphism above amounts to
$$
(R, \tilde{\Theta}) \mapsto (R, R\tilde{\Theta}).
\tag{1}
$$

1. I wouldn't say it's a matter of one definition being more precise than the other, more a matter of which identification in (1) is more useful in a specific situation.
2. Though $\tilde{\Theta} \in \Lie{so}(n) = T_{I} SO(n)$ is skew-symmetric, the product $R\tilde{\Theta}$ generally is not. Instead,
   $$
   (R\tilde{\Theta})^{T} = \tilde{\Theta}^{T} R^{T} = -\tilde{\Theta} R^{-1}.
   $$

Finally, in case it's helpful, the way the definition of Simo *et al.* is written, it looks as if only the product $R\tilde{\Theta}$ is retained, with $R$, the "point of tangency", implicit. By analogy, the tangent bundle of the unit circle may be viewed in two standard ways:

- As the cylinder $S^{1} \times \Reals \subset S^{1} \times \Reals^{2}$.
- As the family of tangent lines to the circle in $\Reals^{2}$.

A point of $\Reals^{2}$ outside the circle (analogous to a product $R\tilde{\Theta}$) only represents a tangent vector once the point of tangency $R$ is specified.

[image: Two views of the tangent bundle]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explaination helps me a lot.